# Why i am getting a Number FormatException?

Tags: java

I made a program on the code chef.I am getting a correct output on my eclipse ide and when i  submitted it the output shown on CodeChef ide is :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: null
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:542)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
at Prog1.stop(Main.java:16)
at Prog1.main(Main.java:50)
```

Here is the question Link:https://www.codechef.com/problems/TEST

Here is my solution to the problem:
//life universe and EveryThing

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

class Prog1 
{
 public static void stop() throws IOException
 {

   BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
   String s1=br.readLine();
   int x=Integer.parseInt(s1);
   int ar[]=new int[x];
   int k=0;
    for(int i=0;i<x;i++)
     {
       BufferedReader br1=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
       String s2=br1.readLine();
       int p=Integer.parseInt(s2);
       ar[k++]=p;
     }
   for(int m=0;m<x;m++)
    {
       System.out.println(ar[m]);
    }
   for(int y=0;y<x;)
    {
        if(ar[y]!=42)
        {
          System.out.println(ar[y]);
          y++;
        }
        else
        {
          break;
        }

    }

}
 public static void main(String s[]) throws IOException
 {
 stop();
 }
}
```

Comment: `Integer.parseInt(s1);` causing `NFE`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The immediate cause is that you're passing `null` into `Integer.parseInt`. Next you need to work out *why* that's happening...

You're creating a new `BufferedReader` wrapping `System.in` on each iteration... that's likely to be reading more than just a single line, which means some of the lines of input are effectively being swallowed.

Just create *one* `BufferedReader` at the start, and use that for the whole program. You could also check whether the return value for `readLine` is `null`, but as that would indicate invalid data it's not awful to just let that throw in the way it already is doing...

Answer (score 2):

Cause:

You are doing `Integer.parseInt()`. That causes exception for  non valid strings and `null`s  etc ..

Solution:

1) Have a `null` check

2) `Try=Catch` it and do necessary in catch.

Answer (score 1):

first do a check `if(s1!=null)` then `int x=Integer.parseInt(s1);` use exception handling concept `try catch`.

```
            try{
                   if(s1!=null){
                       int x=Integer.parseInt(s1);
                   }
               }catch(NumberFormatException e){

               }
```